# Comparing two lists and number of occurrences

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, comparison

What is the best way to compare two lists in Python and to check occurrences?

Consider that

```
list1 = [a, b, c]
list2 = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
```

I need two things:

- to check if `list1` contains elements from `list2` and get back True or False
- to check how many items (`len`?) from `list2` are in `list1` and get back integer of those occurrences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use sets here:

```
intersection = set(list1).intersection(list2)
```

`intersection` is now a set of all elements from `list1` that also occur in `list2`. It's length is the number of occurrences.